# Custom date picker in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I need to use Vuetify [`v-date-picker`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers) in different components. But that will lead to code duplication. So I thought it will be interesting to create a custom `<custom-date-picker />` component which I can use anywhere I need to.

- This child component should emit to the parent the value of the formatted date.
- The parent component has a button which console logs the formatted date

[image]

But with my current code, I am getting this error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"

found in

---> <CustomDatePicker> at components/CustomDatePicker.vue
       <Pages/index.vue> at pages/index.vue
```

**Parent component is pages/index.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <custom-date-picker v-model="date" />
    <v-btn @click="getDate">
      Ok
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CustomDatePicker from '@/components/CustomDatePicker.vue'

export default {
  components: { CustomDatePicker },
  data () {
    return {
      date: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getDate () {
      console.log(this.date)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Child component is components/CustomDatePicker.vue**:

```
<template>
  <v-container fill-height>
    <v-row justify="center" align="center">
      <v-col cols="12">
        <!-- Date picker -->
        <v-menu
          ref="menu1"
          v-model="menu1"
          :close-on-content-click="false"
          transition="scale-transition"
          offset-y
        >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-text-field
              v-bind:value="value"
              v-on:input="$emit('input', $event)"
              @blur="date = parseDate(value)"
              v-on="on"
              value
              label="Date"
              color="green lighten-1"
            />
          </template>
          <v-date-picker
            v-model="date"
            @input="menu1 = false"
            no-title
            header-color="green lighten-1"
            color="green lighten-1"
          />
        </v-menu>
        <!-- end of date picker -->
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CustomDatePicker',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      menu1: null,
      date: null
    }
  },

  computed: {
    computedDateFormatted () {
      return this.formatDate(this.date)
    }
  },

  watch: {
    date (val) {
      this.value = this.formatDate(this.date)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formatDate (date) {
      if (!date) { return null }
      return date
    },
    parseDate (date) {
      if (!date) { return null }

      const [year, month, day] = date.split('-')
      return `${year}-${month.padStart(2, '0')}-${day.padStart(2, '0')}`
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How to overcome my issue ?

This [simple demo](https://github.com/begueradj/custom-date-picker) is available on Github if you have time for it :)

**UPDATE 1:**

I succeeded to get rid of the error message above by avoiding mutating the prop `value`. I can choose the date and when I click on the **Ok** button I get the date console logged properly.

The issue is that the text field of the parent component does not show the date I picked, it stays as it is shown on the picture above.

Here is the updated code of the child component:

```
<template>
  <v-container fill-height>
    <v-row justify="center" align="center">
      <v-col cols="12">
        <!-- Date picker -->
        <v-menu
          ref="menu1"
          v-model="menu1"
          :close-on-content-click="false"
          transition="scale-transition"
          offset-y
        >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="dateFormatted"
              @blur="date = parseDate(dateFormatted)"
              v-on="on"
              value
              label="Date"
              color="green lighten-1"
            />
          </template>
          <v-date-picker
            v-bind:value="value"
            v-on:input="$emit('input', $event)"
            @input="menu1 = false"
            no-title
            header-color="green lighten-1"
            color="green lighten-1"
          />
        </v-menu>
        <!-- end of date picker -->
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CustomDatePicker',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      menu1: null,
      date: null,
      dateFormatted: null
    }
  },

  computed: {
    computedDateFormatted () {
      return this.formatDate(this.date)
    }
  },

  watch: {
    date (val) {
      this.dateFormatted = this.formatDate(this.date)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formatDate (date) {
      if (!date) { return null }
      return date
    },
    parseDate (date) {
      if (!date) { return null }

      const [year, month, day] = date.split('-')
      return `${year}-${month.padStart(2, '0')}-${day.padStart(2, '0')}`
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: *How to overcome my issue* ... I'd suggest you *Avoid mutating a prop directly* and *Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value*

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I avoided now (after I posted the question), I get the chosen date when I clock on the button, but it is not reflected on the text field for the moment (it stays as it is on the picture) @JaromandaX

Comment: Did you post the new code @JaromandaX ?

Comment: I updated my post with relevant code and explanation. @Djip

Comment: I updated my question with half working code @JaromandaX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changes i've made to get it to work, is that i've added a `computed` with a `get()` and `set()`. The getter will return the current selected value, and the setter will be emitting the new value each time it's changing.

This is a good way of utilizing the `v-model` within custom components.

CustomDatePicker.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container fill-height>
    <v-row justify="center" align="center">
      <v-col cols="12">
        <!-- Date picker -->
        <v-menu
          ref="menu1"
          v-model="menu1"
          :close-on-content-click="false"
          transition="scale-transition"
          offset-y
        >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="selected"
              v-on:input="$emit('input', $event)"
              @blur="date = parseDate(value)"
              v-on="on"
              value
              label="Date"
              color="green lighten-1"
            />
          </template>
          <v-date-picker
            v-model="selected"
            @input="menu1 = false"
            no-title
            header-color="green lighten-1"
            color="green lighten-1"
          />
        </v-menu>
        <!-- end of date picker -->
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CustomDatePicker',
    props: {
      value: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        menu1: null,
        date: null
      }
    },

    computed: {
      selected: {
        get() {
          return this.value
        },
        set(value) {
          this.$emit('input', value)
        }
      },
      computedDateFormatted () {
        return this.formatDate(this.date)
      }
    },

    watch: {
      date (val) {
        this.value = this.formatDate(this.date)
      }
    },
    methods: {
      formatDate (date) {
        if (!date) { return null }
        return date
      },
      parseDate (date) {
        if (!date) { return null }

        const [year, month, day] = date.split('-')
        return `${year}-${month.padStart(2, '0')}-${day.padStart(2, '0')}`
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You're welcome, remember to mark the answer as correct if everything seems to work "later" :)

Comment: One small correction. You should not / cannot mutate props directly in the watcher (anywhere else also). So, in the watcher, instead of this.value = this.formatDate(this.date), use it as this.selected = this.formatDate(this.date). And you can remove the parameter, as we are not using it.

watch: {
      date () {
        this.selected = this.formatDate(this.date)
      }
    },